# Custom extension method in typescript

Tags: typescript

Well I was trying to create an extension method for my interface Student

```
declare global {  
  interface Student {  
   CourseOpted(): String;  
  }  
 }  

 Student.prototype.CourseOpted = function(): string {  
  return 'some-string';
 }  
 export {};
```

And when I place cursor on Student:- Getting this error

'Student' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
Was referring this article:- [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-extension-methods-in-typescript/#:~:text=Extension%2Dmethod%20gives%20you%20the,any%20data%2Dtype%20you%20want](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/learn-about-extension-methods-in-typescript/#:%7E:text=Extension%2Dmethod%20gives%20you%20the,any%20data%2Dtype%20you%20want).

What I could notice is;- when we extend class for Interface like String, Number, Array..Extension method is possible. Then why not for the above example.
Please help me! Solve this error

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Edited:-
So we found this ts extension method repo:- https://github.com/staeke/ts-extension-methods

Comment: This might have something to do with your `export` syntax. What happens when you use `export { Student };`

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work

Answer (score 1):

`interface` are a compiled time element. When you compile Typescript into Javascript it does not emit anything for an `interface`. The `interface` purely exist at compile time (to benefit typescript).

The reason why it works for String, Number, etc. because they exist at runtime.

If you want different implementation of the function

- then why not declare `Student` as a `class` with default function implementation and allow a sub-class to override the functional implementation as and when required.

If you want a static implementation

- then simply declare it as a static function inside the `Student` class

Answer (score 0):

`Student` is an `interface`, not `class` you should create class and import it before making any changes. Maybe it is better just to create new class. You may also add serialization to it, if you take students data from server.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUwFcAmFzIDeAsAFDLLA4BcyIWAtgEbQDcZFMwUAzmAHJwGEWnyigA5gBoOyADZw%20g4aLDiQ0sgF8yZBAp49kmXPjCUGABzkRh4Ixmx4CJcpRp1GLKOzddeAkIiyGKSvhQGgSohamG6bggA9iBiWAhgiVAAFHym4LSOeWAAlLJJKWppGdlUtPTM0FLI-kpBqurS8opRwaEapQnJqemZWVQA8lAmzmB1XtDIAD5o02ZNLT0A-O2STZHKENsxHcVEshTAMMhZYACelhCJVxNTTmbIALxfyABEiUwAKwg6R%20p1cFAhyDAAAtgDwAHRUT7uSarcCInDhSFQ2EIjYHZEvNFgeH4oJYyEwuHw-ZBQk4VFvdG04QUiFQCDYKAgNk6NwUKkIpEfFGvIpswWk7itYTIsmyxTHOL8nHUlkoEXq5CKvoSLF82SWLBMOTABDNRKJLJg87IDlckC-JhwKA-fXaeLlPgxIoABmRIAgAHdjEywFlfU0fgApRLQkA-KMAEUSEFBvi9iRsNMSEhyYd9xQzQyzEBzedyM19pMt1qLnqG5krZgAjAHg6Gillwe5aC2ZH5pT1aD8ALLAOQAazgidk6pHAAkIHIJMAftp66Q9CXs3Jc-mii2i0A)

```js
interface IStudent {
  id: number;
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
}

class Student implements IStudent {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(student: IStudent)
  constructor(id: number, firstName: string, lastName: string)
  constructor(idOrStudent: number | IStudent, firstName?: string, lastName?: string) {
    if (typeof idOrStudent === "object") {
      this.id = idOrStudent.id;
      this.firstName = idOrStudent.firstName;
      this.lastName = idOrStudent.lastName;
      return;
    }
    this.id = idOrStudent;
    this.firstName = firstName as string;
    this.lastName = lastName as string;
  }

  public foo() {
    return "bar";
  }
}

const student0 = new Student(0, "John", "Doe");
console.log(student0);
console.log(student0.foo());

const student1 = new Student({
  id: 1,
  firstName: "Milka",
  lastName: "Helgi"
});

console.log(student1);
```